# How to transform monads in a conduit pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, haskell, conduit

I am trying to copy a file from disk to a File in MongoDB GridFS with the Database.MongoDB packages.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  pipe <- MDB.connect (host "127.0.0.1")
  _ <- access pipe master "baseball" run
  close pipe

run :: MDB.Action IO GFS.File
run = do
  uploadImage "sandbox/bat.jpg"

uploadImage :: Text -> MDB.Action IO GFS.File
uploadImage src = do
  bucket <- GFS.openDefaultBucket
  runConduitRes $ sourceFileBS (unpack src) .| (hole $ GFS.sinkFile  bucket src)
```

This does not work because the *sourceFileBS* expects as Resource in the base monad and the *GFS.sinkFile* wants a MongoDB an *Action* (a specialized Reader).

What is an elegant way to connect these pieces of a conduit together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without all of the types and functions available, it's a bit hard to tell you the best way to do it. However, one way that should work looks something like this:

```
withBinaryFile (unpack src) ReadMode $ \h -> runMongo $ runConduit $
  sourceHandle h .| GFS.sinkFile bucket src
```

Comment: I was not yet ready at the time to appreciate your answer. I have now solved the type issues however the program hangs when it hits the conduit. I am going to hit my head a bit more against the keyboard and will post another question if I can't get out as it is something else entirely. Thanks for setting me on the right road!